# Loading the contents of a div from another page, but not the div itself

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's `.load` function to load the contents of div from another document. The code looks like this:

```
$("#projectPagePieces").load("projectInfo.html .pieces");
```

This works successfully in loading the `.pieces` div into `#projectPagePieces`. Howvever, I would instead like to just load the *content* of `.pieces`—everything inside of it—not including the actual `.pieces` div itself. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you have tried `$("#projectPagePieces").load("projectInfo.html .pieces *");`? Maybe can help

Comment: What's the harm caused by the extra div element?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry This has solved it! Thank you!

Comment: @GtwoK good to hear that. I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have tried `$("#projectPagePieces").load("projectInfo.html .pieces *");`? Maybe can help

Answer (score 0):

You could load the HTML into a div thats not your final div, then take the inner content you want and put it in your final div

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#projectPagePieces").load("projectInfo.html .pieces")
    .html( $(this).find(".pieces").html() );
```

Unless the HTML content is quite unwieldy, this should be instantaneous.